# Child views in RelativeLayout not overlapping

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout

I've set up the following layout in `Android`. I expect the `TextView` to overlap on the lower-right hand of the button, as a counter.

Instead of overlapping OVER the button, it "under" laps beneath it. It is never in the foreground.

I know I could use API 21's Elevation property but I want compatibility with earlier devices.

I expected placing the `TextView` after the `Button` to be sufficient to achieve what I want - can't understand why it's not behaving as expected.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <Button
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:id="@+id/chat_request"
        android:background="@drawable/chatbubble"
        android:duplicateParentState="true"
        android:enabled="false"
        android:layout_alignWithParentIfMissing="false"
        android:focusable="false" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="1"
        android:id="@+id/request_counter"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="false"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="false"
        android:background="@drawable/count_background"
        android:textColor="@color/white"

        android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
        android:layout_below="@+id/chat_request"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/chat_request"
        android:layout_marginTop="-15dp"
        android:duplicateParentState="true"
         />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Not sure why this question got downvoted - if the person who did so can give feedback, it would be really helpful for next time! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

try this out:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/chatbubble">

<Button
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:layout_width="60dp"
    android:id="@+id/chat_request"
    android:duplicateParentState="true"
    android:enabled="false"
    android:layout_alignWithParentIfMissing="false"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:background="@color/transparent"/>



<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="1"
    android:id="@+id/request_counter"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="false"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="false"
    android:background="@drawable/count_background"
    android:textColor="@color/white"

    android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
    android:layout_below="@+id/chat_request"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/chat_request"
    android:layout_marginTop="-15dp"
    android:duplicateParentState="true"
    />

 </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Actually the solution here was to use an ImageButton - Button object kept stayed on top.

Comment: Thanks for the info :)

Answer (score 0):

This is due to the fact that I was using a Button element. The Button always supersedes any other element, regardless of its placement on a RelativeLayout.

However when I changed that element to an ImageButton, it adopted the behavior I expected: it overlapped above previous UI elements in the layout, if it was place underneath those elements in the XML.